# VBA Code to sort Column by NO FILL

Tags: vba, excel

Good day Pros
    I have a bunch of Macros that I run together, the last one of them should use column B to sort by NO FILL, so that data that have no background color come to the top of the list. (The data contains about 10, 000 rows and 35 columns, based on the code below, when I used the blue or purple color to be listed first, it works but it does not work for NO FILL. I used 0 and I also used 16777215, but no luck. What am I doing Wrong?
  PS: I could not find any other VBA Code for NO FILL. xlNone or vbWhite does not work either.
   Thank you.

```
Sub ColByNofill()

    'Sub Just(sht As Worksheet)
    Dim rngSort As Range
    Dim rngTable As Range
    Dim sColor As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Worksheets(1)

    sColor = 0 'No Fill

    'sColor = 16777215   ' white color
    'sColor = 10498160    'purple

    'sColor = 15790082 ' blue color

    RowCount = sht.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rngSort = sht.Range("B1:A" & RowCount)
    Set rngTable = sht.Range("B1:" & sht.Cells(RowCount, sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))

    sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sht.Sort.SortFields.Add(rngSort, _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , _
        xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = sColor

    With sht.Sort
        .SetRange rngTable
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Edit on this...I recorded a Macro which gave me this code below ub sortfun()
'
' sortfun Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub but no work

Comment: So i edited it to this code below Sub sortfun()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets(1)

'
' sortfun Macro
'

'
    sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With sht.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub and i get error 91 at sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear when i combine all macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Answer my own Question, All i had to do was to stop assigning the color, so i commented out sColor = 0 and changed sortOnValue.color = xlNone, see the edited code below.

```
Sub ColByNoFill
Dim rngSort As Range
Dim rngTable As Range
Dim sColor As Long

'sColor = 0

RowCount = sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set rngSort = sht.Range("A1:A" & RowCount)
Set rngTable = sht.Range("A1:" & sht.Cells(RowCount, sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))

sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
sht.Sort.SortFields.Add(rngSort, _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , _
    xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = xlNone

With sht.Sort
    .SetRange rngTable
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only a suggestion since I don't really know how to sort the "No Fill" cells to be on the top, but why don't you colour the "No Fill" cells with red, for example, and then sort by colour? After that, you can restore the colour back if necessary. Or you can assign certain values based on the colour list and then sort.

Comment: Oh no, that is not going to work based on the data and other Macros..Cposiba Nastya.

Comment: @John Could you share the picture of your worksheet? And don't ever call me Nastya.

Comment: How do i share the picture? and Sorry for the name, i was a Medical student in Russia for 7yrs, my friends that are Anastasiya are been called Nastya, like Tatyana called Tanya etc. Your name Suggested a former Soviet Union Name that was why. Sorry once again.